# Yii Call beforeSave() in other model's to be Save

Tags: mysql, yii, model, relationship, before-save

I have created two tables as, forum_post and gallery.

### forum_post table:

### id   user_id   ststus   photo_id

1      1       hi...!  NULL
 2      1       hello!  NULL
 3      1       NULL    1

### 4      1       NULL    2

### user_gallery table:

### id    user_id   image    video

1      1       1.jpg    NULL

### 2      1       new.gif  NULL

When, user upload the image file in the user_gallery table, i want to create one row in the forum_post table and store the gallery id into the forum_post-> image field. as well as the user id also stored in the forum_post table.

My model code in the ForumPost is:

```
public static function addForumImage($id, $user_id) {
    $forumImage = ForumPost::model()->find('LOWER(photo_id) = ?',  array( strtolower($image)));
    if (!$forumImage) {
        $forumImage = new ForumPost;
        $forumImage->photo_id = $image;
        $forumImage->save(false);
    }
```

UserGallery beforeSave function is:

```
protected function beforeSave() {
    if (parent::beforeSave()) {

        ForumPost::addForumImage($this->id, $this->user_id);
        // var_dump($forumPost->photo_id);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

My table relationship is, user_gallery->image refers the forum_post->photo_id.

Now, the image is stored in the user_gallery folder and i dint get the id  in the ForumPost model...
Please any  one help me.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
protected function beforeSave() {
    if (parent::beforeSave()) {

        ForumPost::addForumImage($this->id, $this->user_id, $this->forum_image);
        // var_dump($forumPost->photo_id);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Model

```
    public static function addForumImage($id, $user_id,$image) {
        $forumImage = ForumPost::model()->find('photo_id = :image',  array( ':image'=>strtolower($image)));
        if (empty($forumImage)) {
            $forumImage = new ForumPost;
            $forumImage->user_id=$user_id;
            $forumImage->content= NULL
            $forumImage->photo_id = $image;
            $forumImage->save(false);
        }
}
```

Comment: Now i'm getting the following error:
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`nh`.`forum_post`, CONSTRAINT `fk_forum_post_gallery` FOREIGN KEY (`photo_id`) REFERENCES `user_gallery` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE). The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `forum_post` (`status`, `user_id`, `content`, `photo_id`, `updated`, `created`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, :yp2, :yp3, :yp4, :yp5)

Comment: change your method to afterSave()

Comment: this error is coming because you are trying to create a row in a table which has a foreign key. so first create a row in a primary key table

Comment: ok. but without foreign-key relation how can i get the user_gallery id to the forum_post ?